# Onnx format, how it works?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, format, onnx

I have been studying about ONNX and I understand what it is for and basically how it works.

But would you like to understand how it works? I was unable to find information about that. I know that it is done through protobuf but how is the information stored on ONNX and how is it transformed into another model?

Is all the thick part made by using the frameworks functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked this page? https://github.com/onnx/onnx/blob/master/docs/IR.md

ONNX is a specification that defines how models should be constructed (Intermediate Representation) and the operators in the graph. Converters for various frameworks will convert the trained model into the ONNX representation - see https://github.com/onnx/tutorials#converting-to-onnx-format

ONNX and most all the converters are open source for investigating.

If you have further questions, you can also directly post in ONNX github issues.